# Not Able to Select a Class With Parent Specification in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can you please let me know how can I get this done in vanilla JavaScript? I am able to select the `.pay-plan-price` text which it's parent has `active` class like this in jQuery

```
 var fee = $('.plan-box.active .pay-plan-price').text();
```

But I need to do same select in core js format. I tried this

```
var fee = document.getElementsByClassName('.plan-box.active .pay-plan-price');
console.log(fee)
```

but in return I am getting `HTNLCollection` instead of the text of `.pay-plan-price` which has parent `.plan-box.active`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` to select an element using a similar selector as jquery accepts:

```
document.querySelector('.plan-box.active .pay-plan-price');
```

And then of course you need to get a text from that element, so use also `textContent` or `innerText` property on the returned element.

Example:

```
var fee = document.querySelector('.plan-box.active .pay-plan-price').textContent;
console.log(fee);
```

Comment: Thanks Telman just please fix the`loog`  to `log` :-)